# Databricks community - not recognizing columns (Csv file - Python)

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databriks community for the first time and I have a question. I have a simple CSV file showing 7 fields: Hospital, Neighborhood, etc.

I loaded the file using:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWMoo.png)

Then I need to calculate the number of lines and the number of different hospitals in the dataset. When I try to check the number of different hospitals i get the error: cannot resolve '`Hospital`' given input columns: [Hospital;Barrio;Fecha ingreso;Fecha alta;Edad paciente;Sexo paciente;Área de diagnóstico principal];;

(it seems the command does not recognize "Hospital" as a column name.)Any ideas?

Code used:

```
print("Número de hospitales distintos: " + str(df.select("Hospital").distinct().count()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong delimiter - in your code (better to put it as text, not as image!) you're using `,` as delimiter, but your data is delimited by `;`. So change  line `delimiter = ','` to `delimiter = ';'` and it should work